# Multiple chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The goal of this is to have my extension wait for a change in the History, depending on what it says, do a certain action.

Here is what I have so far

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.update({ url: "https://www.WEBSITE.com/messages" });

chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
    if (details.url.indexOf("messages") >= 0) {
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: 'getInboxStats.js'
        });;
    } else {//if (details.url.indexOf("match") >= 0) {
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: 'startBotting.js'
        });;
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    if (message.type == "emptyAmount") {
        emptyAmount = message.content;
        if (!(percentageOfMessages > 0)) {
            percentageOfMessages = 50;
        }
        amountToSend = Math.floor(emptyAmount * (percentageOfMessages / 100));
        alert(amountToSend);
        chrome.tabs.update({ url: "https://www.WEBSITE.com/match" });
    }

});
```

**getInboxStats.js**

```
var currentAmount = document.getElementsByClassName('count')[1].innerHTML;
var maxAmount = document.getElementsByClassName('total')[0].innerHTML;
var emptyAmount = maxAmount - currentAmount;

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ content: emptyAmount, type: "emptyAmount" });
```

**startBotting.js**

```
alert("TEST");
```

The issue I have is that the `getInboxStats.js` starts, but it's like the `onHistoryStateUpdated` only seems to work once because the file `startBotting.js` never displays an alert that says 'TEST'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the purpose of `onHistoryStateUpdated`.

It captures the instances of [history state manipulation without navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) via History API as opposed to regular navigation. When you call `update({url: "..."})` it's a regular navigation.

If you're really concerned about browser history updates, you should be using [`chrome.history.onVisited`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#event-onVisited).

If you want to use `webNavigation` API to capture regular navigations, you should use `onCommitted` event.

You should also look into `chrome.tabs` API.